# Infinite looping; do not understand how

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

In the code below, when I input anything other than an integer value the code does not ask for my input again and just loops the string outputs infinitely. A little help...

```
    int choice = 0;
    while(choice == 0)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Start by typing the choice number from above and hitting enter: ");
            choice = input.nextInt();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        if ((choice == 1) || (choice == 2) || (choice == 3))
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid choice number. Please carefully type correct option.");
            choice = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

When you input a non-integer it will not be consumed. You need to scan past it. This can be done by, for example, adding a `input.nextLine()` statement to your `catch` block. This will consume the invalid input and allow your program to read new data.

This will solve your problem:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    input.nextLine(); // Consume the invalid line
    System.out.println("Invalid choice number. Please carefully type correct option.");
}
```

You could also read the line as a string and try to parse it as a number using `Scanner.nextLine` and `Integer.parseInt`, but I prefer using `nextInt` for integers. It makes the purpose of the code more clear (in my opinion).

Answer (score 2):

When `nextInt` is used and the next input is not an int, it will throw an exception but *not* consume the data, i.e. the next call will return immediately because the data is still present.

You can fix this by calling the `skip` method with a pattern like `[^0-9]*` to skip all invalid input. Then an input like "aaa3" would work. If you want to ignore everything, use `.*` as pattern.

Comment: I got it. I declared a string variable response that takes the value of input.next(). Then I converted it to an int. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `Scanner(system.in);` from the `import java.util.Scanner;` package?
Try adding `input.nextLine();` in the catch to clear the value to stop the infinite loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int choice = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while(choice == 0)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Start by typing the choice number from above and hitting enter: ");
        choice = input.nextInt();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Invalid choice number. Please carefully type correct option.");
    }

    if ((choice == 1) || (choice == 2) || (choice == 3))
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid choice number. Please carefully type correct option.");
        choice = 0;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Oh. What's the issue then? It works fine for me... Just needs an extra break in catch...

Comment: Extra break? I'm not sure what you mean. The problem is the infinite loop for non-integer input.

Comment: You must use `nextLine()` otherwise you just get another exception like the first one.

Comment: I knew what I meant, just wrote the wrong function, which isn't very helpful is it. I've changed it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that you are not consuming the remaining data in the stream.  I solved it with the following code, although you will want to document you code better before you use it in a program:

```
int choice = 0;
while(choice == 0)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.print("Start by typing the choice number from above and hitting enter: ");
        choice = input.nextInt();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        input.next();
        System.out.println("Invalid choice number. Please carefully type correct option.");
    }

    if ((choice == 1) || (choice == 2) || (choice == 3))
    {
        break;
    }
    choice = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify and reduce your code as follows:

```
    int choice;
    System.out.println("Start by typing the choice number from above and hitting enter: ");
    while(true)
    {
        try {
            choice = input.nextInt();
            if ((choice == 1) || (choice == 2) || (choice == 3))
                break;
        } catch(InputMismatchException e) {  // handle only the specific exception
            input.nextLine();                // clear the input
        }
    System.out.println("Invalid choice number. Please carefully type correct option.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in the line `choice = input.nextInt();` 
choice value is always 0. Print choice soon after that.

Also for non integer value add a condition to break from the loop.